# Using 3-way valves as 2-way valves

Tags: control-engineering, hvac

A question was asked by another user about the cons of using a 3-way valve as a 2-way valve. The responses mainly talked about the non-linear control characteristics that pop up due to shutting off one line. The problem of a bypass line was not addressed. Upon further reading, I came across a white paper by Armstrong Pumps about the same, wherein the furthest 3-way valve had all lines kept open, creating a virtual bypass line that comes into effect only when flow is satisfied in all the other lines. My question is, what are the drawbacks of doing this? On the surface, this idea looks very promising and exciting (!).

The reason I need to do this is because I plan to add VAV boxes to an existing CAV system, built and commissioned in 1998 in India. I feel that adding just the VAV, but not optimising the flow of cooling water, would not lead to realisation of the potential savings here. Any thoughts are welcome.